# how to apply the func for textfield underline code to all text fields

Tags: swift3

I want to reuse the code for all the text field in my screen there is the function i have written for a single textfield out of all how do I apply it to all the text field how to customise it so that only single code will work for all: code is Here:

```
func textfieldborder()
{
    let border = CALayer()
    let width = CGFloat(1.0)
    border.borderColor = UIColor.darkGray.cgColor
    border.frame = CGRect(x: CGFloat(0), y: textname.frame.size.height - width, width:  textname.frame.size.width, height: textname.frame.size.height)

    border.borderWidth = width
    textname.layer.addSublayer(border)
    textname.layer.masksToBounds = true

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make your function accept a parameter of type `UITextField`.

```
func textfieldborder(_ textField: UITextField) {
    let border = CALayer()
    let width = CGFloat(1.0)
    border.borderColor = UIColor.darkGray.cgColor
    border.frame = CGRect(x: CGFloat(0), y: textField.frame.size.height - width, width:  textField.frame.size.width, height: textField.frame.size.height)

    border.borderWidth = width
    textField.layer.addSublayer(border) // note that you are setting properties of textField the parameter now!
    textField.layer.masksToBounds = true
}
```

You can call this method on all the text fields you want a border on:

```
textfieldBorder(textname)
textfieldBorder(textFoo)
textfieldBorder(textBar)
```